# How do you send events in R Shiny to Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, google-analytics

I am trying to track user interactions in R Shiny using Google Analytics. I have been referring to the following guides:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html

I have the following Java script saved as `google-analytics.html`:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
  

        
  $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
     if (event.name === 'hub') {
       ga('send','event', 'input', 
          'updates', event.name, event.value);
       }
     });     
      
     
  $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if(event.name === 'hub'){
       alert('Changed Hub');
       }
     }); 
     
  $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
     alert('Connected to the server');
  
    });          
</script>
```

Right now this is tracking people that are in the app, but it is not sending the event information when they change information in the `hub` input. I added the two alerts at the end of the script to make sure I am identifying the correct object and, sure enough, when the user changes the `hub` input, they get an alert.

The short version of the `ui` is as follows:

```
ui <-
   fluidPage(
               
               tags$head(includeHTML(("google-analytics.html"))),
               
               # Sidebar
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   radioButtons("hub", label = h3("Hub"),
                                choices = list("Location 1", "Location 2",
                                               "Both"), 
                                selected = "Location 1"))), 
              
               # Main Panel
               mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("test"))
)
```

The `server` is not relevant, but if needed, a play example is as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$test<-renderPrint({input$hub})
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Why isn't the event being sent to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `gtag.js` code and `analytics.js` code.

You are using `gtag` as library so you have to send an event with this code:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

In your case use this:

```
gtag('event', 'updates', {
  'event_category': 'input',
  'event_label': event.name,
  'value': event.value
});
```

instead of this:

```
ga('send','event', 'input', 
   'updates', event.name, event.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you know how I could store the value of the event if it is a string? For example, if the user changes hub to "Location 2", then I want "Location 2" to be sent. So, I could change "updates" to event.name and put event.something in its place.

Comment: You're welcome. For your question, since this is not an analytics question but the use of the R system to store the information I suggest you create a new question with specific tags so that R users can help you.

Comment: Hello everyone i use the exact same html but on my google analitic page i have an issue. it detect when i connect but i can't see any made up event like " ubdate" or any alerte. nor in "real time" nether in events on report. i it me that isn't looking to the right place or has it change since last year ?